# Finding out coreutils incompatibilities between Alpine and "normal" Linux (eg. Ubuntu)

Tags: coreutils, alpine-linux

I've fighted with non-working gitlab build.

I've needed to sanitize output of psql by removing some non-printables, I've found out the command:

```
<psql invoke> | tr -cd [:print:]
```

Happily testing it locally (Ubuntu) I've commited the changes, but the pipeline has failed. After a few tries with adding debug output, I've logged into `docker:latest` image (based on Alpine) to find out, that `tr` on Alpine doesn't support classes like `[:print:]`.

I have a bunch of scripts that invoke coreutils, and now all of them are potentially incompatibile with Alpine. How to find out what incompatibilites are there between coreutils from Alpine and those form normal Linux like Ubuntu? What adaptations need to be taken so that the shell scripts would run on both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses GNU coreutils. Alpine uses busybox. Busybox places emphasis on providing tiny executables, and so tends to be a lot more stripped down than the GNU utilities. The most reliable way to determine what will work on Alpine would be to read the manpages or other documentation from the busybox project, and/or to install and test with busybox itself. Where you would normally type `tr`, use `busybox tr` instead and see if the result is as expected.

Note that busybox *does* support POSIX-style character classes (`[:upper:]` and friends) but according to [the source](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/tr.c), `[:print:]` and `[:graph:]` are "TODO".  Only the following classes are supported: `alpha`, `alnum`, `digit`, `lower`, `upper`, `space`, `blank`, `punct`, `cntrl`, and `xdigit`. Note that the copyright date at the top of the linked source is 1997. This was the first copy I found; there may have been updates since then.